# How to permanently disable delayed Ack?

Tags: networking, rhel

I have run in to the Nagle / Delayed ACK problem that causes 40ms overhead on small TCP packets.

According to Redhat documentation I can add the `quickack 1` option to the route and it will disable the Delayed ACK feature.

So, this is what I did:

```
[root@x]# ip route show
default via 10.100.11.1 dev ens192 proto static metric 100
10.100.11.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.11.13 metric 100
```

And then I added the quickack option to my interface:

```
[root@x]# ip route change 10.100.11.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.11.13 metric 100 quickack 1
```

This solved the problem.

However, how do I make this change permanent? Or is this even the best method for disabling this feature?

I tried to add `10.100.11.0/24 dev ens192 proto kernel scope link src 10.100.11.13 metric 100 quickack 1` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-ens192` but it did not persist.

I am using RHEL 7.9.

Comment: Not sure how helpful it is at the moment, but it looks like the functionality is being added to NetworkManager: https://github.com/NetworkManager/NetworkManager/blob/c47edbb199ce5dd8b442de0b0dfd296dcfdcfebd/src/libnm-core-impl/nm-setting-ip4-config.c